# strtol() returns an incorrect value

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, string

I've got a weird one here. strtol, atol and atoi all return an incorrect value when I pass in the following string:

```
long test = strtol("3087663490", &p, 10);
```

According to my debugger it returns 2147483647. I'm completely stumped on this. Any advice?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your value is larger than what a signed `long` type can represent. Try:

```
unsigned long test = strtoul("3087663490", &p, 10);
```

(You're getting 2147483647 since it is `LONG_MAX` or 0x7FFFFFFF)

Answer (score 11):

Correctly testing for errors from `strtol()` is tricky.  You need code similar to the below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    char *n = "3087663490";
    char *p;
    long test;

    errno = 0;
    test = strtol(n, &p, 10);

    if (p == n)
        printf("No digits found.\n");
    else if ((test == LONG_MIN || test == LONG_MAX) && errno == ERANGE)
        printf("Value out of range.\n");
    else
        printf("Value is %ld\n", test);

    return 0;
}
```

Running this shows what your problem is - `Value out of range.`.  Use a wider type, like `long long` (and `strtoll()`).

Answer (score 4):

It appears `long` is a 32-bit type on your system.  If that's the case, `3087663490` is larger than `LONG_MAX`.  From the [`strtol(3)` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol):

> If an overflow occurs, **`strtol()`** returns **`LONG_MAX`**.

You need to use an unsigned type to represent that number on your machine:

```
unsigned long test = strtoul("3087663490", &p, 10);
```

Should work fine.

Comment: ..or, a `long long` type and `strtoll()`.

Answer (score 0):

After returning from strtol check the value of `p`. I believe that if you went over the size limit the return value will be LONG_MAX *and* the pointer will still be pointer at a digit rather than whitespace or text.

And I also see after checking that `errno` will be set to `ERANGE`.