# Convert ASCII string to int/float/long

Tags: c

I have this code to convert an ASCII string to and int, float, or double. However, it prints "42" for all of them. Where did I go wrong? The syntax looks correct, no warnings.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
     char *buf1 = "42";
     char buf2[] = "69.00";
     int i;
     double d;
     long l;
     i = atoi(buf1);
     l = atol(buf1);
     d = atof(buf2);
     printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n", i, l, d);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting question. I wrote some code to do this not to long ago. check it out here: https://github.com/rmccullagh/snippets/blob/master/c/ascii/main.c

Comment: You have 3 different types, yet you use the same format string for all of them in your printf.  Use the right format string for each type.

Comment: Don't use `ato*`. There's no way to tell if a returned `0` is a valid result or an error.

Comment: try `#include <stdio.h>` and `printf("%d\t%ld\t%f\n", i, l, d);`

Comment: "no warnings": gcc emits a warning when it detects mismatching arguments to `printf`.

Comment: Depending on what flags you compiled with, you may not see warnings under any circumstance.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Mindblown. Such a small mistake, thanks.

Comment: The mistake is not so much of using incorrect format specifiers, but not compiling with a compiler enabled to warn about such mistakes.

Comment: I have gcc at the highest warning level, so now it is fixed.

Comment: The title is about "int/float/double", yet the code is about `int`, `double`, `long`.  Suggest making title coherent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should avoid use of the `ato*` functions (ie: `atoi`, `atof`, etc), because there are cases where the conversion failed, and it just returns zero, so you have no way to know if the input was really a string representing zero, or if it was due to a processing error. If you modify the example below, for example, and change `buf2` to `"z16"`, you will get a warning you can handle. `atoi` would not let you know about that error.

Second, your format specifiers are incorrect in your `printf` call. Your compiler should have generated warnings about this.

Please refer to the example below for a working version that includes conversion error handling. Not that the explicit casting of `strtol` to `(int)` in my example does allow for a potential integer overflow. Try making `buf1` a large number, and see what happens.

Good luck!

**Code Listing**

---

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* printf */
#include <stdlib.h>  /* strtox */
#include <errno.h>   /* error numbers */

#define BASE         (10)  /* use decimal */

int main(void) {
   char* errCheck;
   char *buf1   = "42";
   char *buf2   = "16";
   char  buf3[] = "69.00";
   int i;
   double d;
   long l;

   /* Handle conversions and handle errors */
   i = (int)strtol(buf1, &errCheck, BASE);
   if(errCheck == buf1) {
      printf("Conversion error:%s\n",buf1);
      return EIO;
   }
   l = strtol(buf2, &errCheck, BASE);
   if(errCheck == buf2) {
      printf("Conversion error:%s\n",buf2);
      return EIO;
   }
   d = strtod(buf3, &errCheck);
   if(errCheck == buf3) {
      printf("Conversion error:%s\n",buf3);
      return EIO;
   }

   printf("%d\t%ld\t%lf\n", i, l, d);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Although using `strtox()` is better than `atox()`, code here also fails to detect overflow and potential garbage at the end of `bufn`, much like `atox()`.

Comment: Fair enough. He could test against LONG_MAX, etc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493235/strtol-returns-an-incorrect-value  Also, a quick `isalpha` loop would handle trailing garbage. The general point I was making was to avoid `atox` functions.

Comment: This answer implies that `atoi` returns 0 on error, which is false. The behavior on errors is unspecified, and the behavior if the value overflows is *undefined*. This is much more serious and makes it basically impossible to use `atoi` unless you know the input is valid and in-range.

Comment: @R.. I stand corrected. It seems it returns zero only if the first character is non-integral. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871711/atoi-how-to-identify-the-difference-between-zero-and-error

Comment: @Dogbert: Even that doesn't seem to be specified.

Comment: @R.. *If the first sequence of non-whitespace characters in str is not a valid integral number, or if no such sequence exists because either str is empty or it contains only whitespace characters, no conversion is performed and zero is returned.*  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: Parenthesizing a positive numeric literal like 10 is a sign of too much paranoia. Rule of thumb: parenthesize if there's an operator in the replacement text. Everything else is a sign of someone not grokking C :-)

Comment: @Jens It is not a sign of paranoia. It is there to appease static code analysis tools (MISRA chk, LINT) etc, so you can sign off on compliance with certain standards legally. Old habits die hard.

Comment: @Dogbert Which MISRA checker warns for unparenthezied numeric literals? The ones I use (flexelint, polyspace) want the *parameters, if any* parenthesized, and expressions with operators. They don't require the replacement text parenthesized if it is a single numeric token. (Programmers beware: -1 is an expression which needs to be parenthesized).

Comment: @Jens I think you just answered your own question. `(-1)` evaluates as a signed integer literal, just like `(1)` evaluates to a literal. Wind River Workbench. This also enforces consistency throughout the code. A decent example would be using a type of globally-accessible offset encoded as a signed integer. If it changes from say, `(2)` to `(-1)`, it's silly that the definition should change based on range. Depending on your master rule override file, your static code analysis tools might also do this to, but the option could be disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Change

`printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n", i, l, d);`

to

```
printf("%d\t%ld\t%f\n", i, l, d);
```

Comment: `stdlib.h` is needed for `atoi`, etc. Both headers are needed.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use `ato*` functions as `ato*` functions has been deprecated by `strto*` and should not be used in new code.

The problem with `ato*` is, if the converted value is out of range it causes ***undefined behavior***.

For more information check [here.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atoi.html)

Comment: With "... `ato*` functions are obsolete".  Do you have some reference that indicates obsolescence?  The `ato*` functions are in the latest C spec. (C11).

Comment: Kindly check **Implementation Notes** section:
http://www.codecogs.com/library/computing/c/stdlib.h/atoi.php

Comment: Suggest editing your answer to match your reference indicating that functions are deprecated.